# adding user given input to already existing list in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im trying to create an app for pizza shop,here the admin gives the new pizza name so that it is added to the already existing menu.And also I have check boxes for the pizza size,so when the admin gives the pizza name, admin will also check-box the size of the pizza and that is also added to the menu.When the specific item is selected from drop down it should list the size available for that selected item. So I have created the text box and the check-boxes. The problem I face here is when I check the size all the check boxes are getting checked and also not getting added to the menu list. Please help me to put the inputs properly in the menu list.

This how I have declared the $scope so when the mushroom is selected it will list sizes 'small' and 'medium'.

```
 $scope.customerList=[
 {'name':'mushroom', 'types':['Small', 'Medium']},
```

[link to plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0UcuvzXgNSAiNJlLXEfE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your template with this

```
<form> 
  <ul>
      <li>Small</li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1"  ng-model='types.small' ng-value='small' />
      </label>

      <li>Medium</li>
      <label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2"  ng-model='types.medium' ng-value='medium' />
      </label>
    </ul>

    <button ng-click="getSelectedCheckboxes(types)">ADD</button>
</form>
```

and put these in your controller

```
$scope.selectedTypes = [];
 $scope.getSelectedTypes= function(types) {
    $scope.selectedArray=[];
     $scope.selectedTypes = angular.copy(types);
     angular.forEach($scope.selectedTypes, function(value, key) {
        if(value){
        $scope.selectedArray.push(key);
        }
     });
     console.log($scope.selectedArray);
 };
```

I think this is what you want . Thanks

Comment: will this help in pushing the selected option into the existing scope [i,e $scope.customerList]

Comment: by using radio buttons user will select only one type but  what if user wants to select mutliple entries. I think check box should be used